# Converting words with String upper() does not work for certain letters?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

Hello guys I hope you can help me with this problem, I've have hours trying to solve it

Using this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

frase = 'La canción de la piña'
print frase.upper()
```

I just get "LA CANCIóN DE LA PIñA", the problem is that it does not make the "ñ" in to a "Ñ" or "ó" in "Ó"

Any idea ?

Comment: Works like a dream in `python3`, in `python2` you need to make unicode strings (`u'')` explicitly.

Answer (score 6):

Use unicode literal (string literal with leading `u`) to represent unicode string:

```
>>> frase = u'La canción de la piña'
>>> print frase.upper()
LA CANCIÓN DE LA PIÑA
```

**UPDATE**

Adding following line at the beginning of the file enables automatic unicode literals. (In interactive shell, statements follow the import statements will be affected.)

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

See [`__future__` - future statement definitions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html).

Comment: `from __future__ import unicode_literals` may enable Unicode literals by default.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, Thank you for the information. I updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Unicode Literal:

Try this:

frase = u'La canción de la piña'